# Аргумент функции зависит от другого

Tags: python, python-3.x

Задание:

> Описать рекурсивную (логическую) функцию, проверяющую, является ли симметричной часть строки, начинающаяся i-ым и заканчивающаяся j-ым элементом.

```
def summ(s: str, i=0, j=len(s)):
    s = s[i:j+1]
    if len(s) == 1:
        return True
    else:
        print(f"_{s}_, {s[0]}_{s[-1]}")
        return s[0] == s[-1] and summ(s[1:-1])

print(summ("abrtrba"))
print('-'*30)
print(summ("abrt1ba"))
```

Этот код, что логично, выдает ошибку, что не знает переменной s, поэтому функция len() не сработает. Подскажите как реализовать.
Вопрос в том, как мне присвоить аргументу j значение длины строки s по умолчанию.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: присвоить значение переменно j _внутри_ функции?

Comment: @strawdog, да так работает, я так и сделал, но возможно есть ещё какой то способ.

Comment: а зачем нужен еще какой-то способ? как вы себе представляете еще какой-то способ?

Comment: Передавать в функцию отдельно параметр, который функция могла бы получить сама через другой переданный параметр - не очень хорошая идея. Лучше, когда источник данных один и не может быть никаких противоречий в переданных данных.